# Is it correct to say: I am a tutor to professionals.

Tags: grammar

I think this is grammatically correct. However, I am not sure if it sounds natural to say it this way.  I know that I can say I am a tutor of foreign professionals.  I really wanted to say: "....my experience as a tutor to professionals.

Comment: Sounds fine to me.

Comment: 'I am a tutor to ...' emphasises the service you provide; 'I am a tutor of ...' sounds rather more proprietorial. Choose the former (and include 'foreign').

Comment: Google Books initial estimates for *tutor **to/of/for** non-native* suggest that ***to*** is the most common preposition, but that's presumably based on flawed logic regarding how common each individual word or two-word pair is. Scrolling through the results gives the actual totals ***to**:20, **of**:5, **for**:50*. Personally I think ***for***, which is inherently more "natural" has stronger overtones of *I provide a service **for** [a certain customer base]*, whereas ***to*** tends to imply ***to** [a certain customer base] I am a service provider* (or even *I am **the** service provider*).

Answer (score 2):

In the USA tutor would be grammatically correct, in the UK the term is for something akin to a teaching assistant.

What do you think of using the term coach or mentor?

I use the term consultant (assistance in passing state medical surveys), I think a tutor is for students trying to pass Statistics: 101  Using mentor/business coach would likely be perceived as something a professional would seek.

Bill B RN BSN RNG

Comment: Thank you everyone for sharing your knowledge and opinion.  The differences are much clearer now.  :)